# Testing UITableView's section footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to test a UISegmentedControl in a UITableView, which is created in the UITableViewDelegate method:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section])];
        [self.segmentedControl setCenter:container.center];
        [container addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
        return container;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView viewForFooterInSection:section];
    }
}
```

In the test class:

```
-(void)testSegmentedControl {
    MyTableViewController *viewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];

    // Getting the footer via the delegate is cheating IMO.
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer =  [viewController.tableView footerViewForSection:0];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = footer.subviews[0];
    // do stuff to the segmentControl then check the tableView.
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm currently manipulating the `UISegmentedControl` via a global property (`viewController.segmentedControl`) and then calling `[viewController.tableView reloadData]` to update the state of the `UITableViewCell`s. But it seems to me that getting the footer from `[viewController.tableView footerViewForSection:0]` is the correct way to test. Any guidance is appreciated.

**Edit:**

As suggested by John Rodgers, I've tried dequeuing a UITableViewHeaderFooterView like we'd do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:self.footerReuseId];
        if (footer == nil) {
            footer = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc]initWithReuseIdentifier:self.footerReuseId];
        }
        if (![footer.subviews containsObject:self.segmentedControl]) {
            [footer addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
        }
        return footer;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView viewForFooterInSection:section];
    }
}
```

No improvement in the test method:

```
-(void)testSegmentedControl {
    MyTableViewController *viewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer1 = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)[viewController.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:viewController.footerReuseId];
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer2 = [viewController.tableView footerViewForSection:0];
    // Break point shows that footer1 and footer2 are nil.
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `viewController.tableView` has been initialised?

Comment: It's initialized. As far as I can tell, calling `[viewController.tableView reloadData]` loads the UITableView with updated data. Setting break points  and judging from the previously working tests confirm this is the case.

Comment: Tried `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`?

Comment: That's the entire point of this question. I want to test that the UITableView has a footer with the UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having here, is that `footerViewForSection` is actually a UITableView method that's used provide it with the view for that section.

You're going to have to dequeue a reusable UITableViewHeaderFooterView in order to test it in your test class:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:mySectionFooterViewIdentifier];
```

This is exactly what you should be using *in your `footerViewForSection`* method you provide for your table view, you're just dequeueing it in the test class instead.

Hope this helps!

~ J

Comment: Just a niggle, but `footerViewForSection:` isn't a delegate method; It's a method for `UITableView`. `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` is a method for the `UITableViewDelegate` class. I've done what you've suggested and updated the question with some results.